# When, where and how to add class to the document.body when using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am doing this, but this is not the react.js way, right? Is render() the right place? What is the alternative?

```
  var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      if (this.state.touchMode === 2) {
          $('body').addClass('touchMode');
      }

      return (<div> etc /div>)
    }
  )}
```

Comment: Why would you use Jquery when this can be achieved by plain javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's best to keep this logic outside of your component.  Event emitters are a good way to abstract this.

```
var globalEvents = new EventEmitter();

var App = React.createClass({
  setTouchMode: function(touchMode){
     globalEvents.emit('touchModeChange', touchMode);
  },
  render: ...
});

// outside any react class
globalEvents.on('touchModeChange', function(mode){
  if (mode === 2) {
    $('body').addClass('touchMode');
  }
  else {
    $('body').removeClass('touchMode');
  }
});
```

If it really needs to be part of the state of one or more components, they can also listen to the event and update their state in the handler.

Answer (score 22):

Well ideally adding a class to the body would break the encapsulation that React components provide and fiddling with the DOM outside React could cause trouble if the body gets re-rendered. If possible, rather than adding the class to the document body, I would just add it to a component root element that React manages.

But to answer your question, you could do that way, but how often is your `this.state.touchMode` would change? If it's something that only changes during mount/unmount of the component, you can do it in `componentWillMount` (so that it only runs once when component mount, rather than every single time during render):

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    document.body.classList.add('touchMode');
},
componentWillUnmount: function(){
    document.body.classList.remove('touchMode');
}
```