# Prevent scrolling using CSS on React rendered components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I render a component via React within my `html` like so:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <div id=app>${appHtml}</div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Within my app I have a burger button, that `onClick` goes full screen.

However, the body is scrollable. I'd normally add a class to the `body` tag and make it `overflow: hidden` to prevent this. However, my react component is rendered within the `body` tag so I have no control over toggling classes based on a click within a react component.

Has anyone got any ideas/advice on how i'd achieve what i'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When, where and how to add class to the document.body when using React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694570/when-where-and-how-to-add-class-to-the-document-body-when-using-react-js)

Comment: link:-https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky

Answer (score 84, accepted):

"I have no control over toggling classes based on a click within a react component."

Not necessarily true!

It's good that you're thinking in a "React-ful" way and wary about modifying the DOM. The main reason you want to avoid doing DOM manipulation is because it causes conflicts between what React is trying to render and the unknown changes you might be trying to make. But in this case you're not manipulating the DOM that React is rendering, you're manipulating its *parent*. In that case you would be totally fine doing something like this:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
```

Or

```
document.body.classList.add("no-scroll")
```

Or whatever works. You're totally safe because React only renders the DOM within `#app` and doesn't care about what happens in its parent. In fact many apps and websites use React in only a small part of the page, to render a single component or widget, instead of an entire app.

That aside, there is an even better, more "React-ful" way to do what you want. Simply restructure your app in such a way that the scrolling container is within your React app instead of `body`. The structure might look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="scroll-container">
        <!-- the rest of your app -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Make `body` overflow hidden, and `body` and `#app` fill the entire screen, and you can control whether `#scroll-container` allows scrolling or not entirely within React.

Comment: Thanks man! I actually thought react would just complain if you tried to change anything outside it's component. I never knew you could still do that.

Comment: there's no dom on nextjs

Answer (score 8):

The above doesn't work for iOS mobile.

[body-scroll-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock) uses a combination of CSS and JS to make it work for all devices, whilst maintaining scrollability of a target element (eg. modal).

ie. for iOS, need to detect when the bottom or top of a target element is reached, and then stop scrolling completely

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Does `body-scroll-lock` let you to prevent a parent element to scroll when its child has been scrolled all way down to the bottom or to the top?

Comment: @RaulSauco I had to do a bit of playing around with it myself, check out my answer in this question.

Comment: tried `body-scroll-lock` does not worked for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971048/how-to-prevent-scrolling-of-body-which-works-also-in-ios-mobile

Answer (score 4):

use React.useEffect() hook to disable scrolling on a specific page then cleanup.
e.g

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    return () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = "scroll"
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to use the body-scroll-lock library with reactjs...

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { disableBodyScroll, enableBodyScroll } from 'body-scroll-lock';

// Components
import Hamburger from './HeaderComponents/Hamburger.js';
import MegaDropdown from './HeaderComponents/MegaDropdown.js';

const Header = props => {
  // variables
  const [isSideNavShown, setIsSideNavShown] = useState(false);
  const [isDropdownShowing, setIsDropdownShowing] = useState(false);

  isDropdownShowing ? disableBodyScroll(document) : enableBodyScroll(document)

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <Hamburger isDropdownShowing={isDropdownShowing} setIsDropdownShowing={setIsDropdownShowing} />
      <MegaDropdown isDropdownShowing={isDropdownShowing} setIsDropdownShowing={setIsDropdownShowing} />
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

in particular the line `isDropdownShowing ? disableBodyScroll(document) : enableBodyScroll(document)`

This allows for when the content in my dropdown fills up to the point where it needs to add a scroll to it, the window(body) scroll is disabled while the dropdown is showing(covering my whole screen). So even though the window(body) scroll is disabled, I can still scroll through my dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents: you can set the height of div containing your content to 100% ( height: 100%)
Or in this case body { height: 100%}

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using css `position: "sticky"` , but I guess that's not what is questioned here. But it worked for me. The other solutions are better I guess.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple way to achieve this in a functional components with Hooks (React 16.8 +) is using `useEffect` to perform side effects.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const html = document.querySelector("html");
    if (html) {
      html.style.overflow = state.isMenuOpen ? "hidden" : "auto";
    }
  }, [state.isMenuOpen]); // condition to watch to perform side effect
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a tiny hook to handle the body scroll.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useSetBodyScroll() {
  const [bodyScroll, setBodyScroll] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resetOnResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 1023) document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) document.body.style.overflow = "scrolls";
    };

    if (!bodyScroll) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
      window.addEventListener("resize", resetOnResize);
    }

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resetOnResize);
    };
  }, [bodyScroll]);

  return setBodyScroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Next.JS you can use:

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html');
if (html) {
  html.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```

And you can reset it with:

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html');
if (html) {
  html.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. As far as I can tell there is no way to dynamically update the styling of the <html> tag of the root layout in the Next.js app router unless you wanted to pass a ref all the way down the the component that needed it. @Gipfeli would this affect other pages that use the same root layout? The useEffect hook might be important here.