# React: Prevent scroll when modal is open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom modal component. When it's open, there is no scrolling whatsoever in the background.

I tried this code below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
}
```

Which seems to work at first, but when I use the modal component, in another page, there is no scroll even when the modal is closed.

Is there a better solution for this?

My modal component:

```
export class Modal extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.showAt ?
                this.props.show ?
                    <div style={style} className={`${this.props.sectionName} ${modalTypeStyle ? modalTypeStyle : styles.modalWhite} ${modalTypeSize ? modalTypeSize : styles.modalSmall} ${!this.props.showAt ? styles.modalWhiteFixed : ""}`}>
                        {this.props.arrowShape ? <div className={arrowTypeStyle ? arrowTypeStyle : styles.triangleToprightWhite} /> : null}
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                    : null
                :
                this.props.show ?
                    <div className={`${this.props.className} ${styles.modal}`}>
                        <div style={style} className={`${this.props.sectionName} ${modalTypeStyle ? modalTypeStyle : styles.modalWhite} ${modalTypeSize ? modalTypeSize : styles.modalSmall} ${!this.props.showAt ? styles.modalWhiteFixed : ""}`}>
                            {this.props.arrowShape ? <div className={arrowTypeStyle ? arrowTypeStyle : styles.triangleToprightWhite} /> : null}
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    </div> :
                    null}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If it works on one page, what is preventing it working on the other page you mention? I did a quick Google search and found that your approach is indeed recommended by others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962757/prevent-scrolling-using-css-on-react-rendered-components.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit weird. On the other page the `overflow: hidden` was already there when the page was loaded. Maybe something related with `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: The problem is you're using `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` in `componentDidMount`. Even if you're not showing the modal, the component still gets mounted which calls the lifecycle method that hides the scroll on body.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought :/. Any ideas to fix this, @HemantParashar?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use state to track if the Modal is open and only hide scroll if it's true. Since you're using `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` in `componentDidMount`, the component still gets mounted which calls the lifecycle method that hides the scroll on body.

```
export class Modal extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open:false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {    
  if(this.state.open){
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }    
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.showAt ?
                this.props.show ?
                    <div style={style} className={`${this.props.sectionName} ${modalTypeStyle ? modalTypeStyle : styles.modalWhite} ${modalTypeSize ? modalTypeSize : styles.modalSmall} ${!this.props.showAt ? styles.modalWhiteFixed : ""}`}>
                        {this.props.arrowShape ? <div className={arrowTypeStyle ? arrowTypeStyle : styles.triangleToprightWhite} /> : null}
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                    : null
                :
                this.props.show ?
                    <div className={`${this.props.className} ${styles.modal}`}>
                        <div style={style} className={`${this.props.sectionName} ${modalTypeStyle ? modalTypeStyle : styles.modalWhite} ${modalTypeSize ? modalTypeSize : styles.modalSmall} ${!this.props.showAt ? styles.modalWhiteFixed : ""}`}>
                            {this.props.arrowShape ? <div className={arrowTypeStyle ? arrowTypeStyle : styles.triangleToprightWhite} /> : null}
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    </div> :
                    null}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The component receives by props from the parent, if the modal is open or not. Even like that, it should work, right? `this.props.open` instead of `this.state.open`?

Comment: Yeah it wil work with props too. Do accept the answer and upvote if you find it helpful.Happy coding !

Comment: You could create a wrapper around the Modal component to simplify & encapsulate things:





`class MyModal extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.oldValue = document.body.style.overflow;
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.style.overflow = this.oldValue;
    }
    render() {
        return <Modal {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Modal>;
    }
}`

Answer (score 54):

in functional component
for when mount or unmount

```
  useEffect(() => {
     document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
     return ()=> document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
  }, []);
```

or when `show` is change or etc

```
  useEffect(() => {
     show && document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
     !show && document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
  }, [show ]);
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to directly add styles to the dom element? Will it have any performance issues or unwanted rerenders?

Comment: This is a good solution using hooks, but your second example has a syntax error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Instead of `show && obj.key = val`, use `show && (obj.key = val)`

Comment: Also setting `"unset"` on unmount is actually adding a style to the body (if overflow is not set as an inline style on the body).  If no inline style is present, just say `document.body.style.overflow = ""`

Comment: I have the same problem, when i tried this, it throw an error : useEffect hook has a messing dependency show !

Comment: @kevbost try this
useEffect(() => {
    if(show) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'unset'
    }
  }, [show]);
This should work

Comment: Looks so beautiful & clean against clumsy Class Component code, thanks for sharing

Comment: Slightly more concise syntax that also fixes the syntax error:

`useEffect(() => (document.body.style.overflow = isOpen ? "hidden" : "unset"), [isOpen]);`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in a `useEffect` within my modal component. Then if your modal itself needs scroll capability just add `overflow-y: scroll;` to the css for that element

Answer (score 37):

Here is a custom hook you can use for functional components.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const useDisableBodyScroll = (open) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
    }
  }, [open]);
};
```

```
export const Modal = (props) => {
    useDisableBodyScroll(props.show);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props.showAt ?
                props.show ?
                    <div style={style} className={`${props.sectionName} ${modalTypeStyle ? modalTypeStyle : styles.modalWhite} ${modalTypeSize ? modalTypeSize : styles.modalSmall} ${!props.showAt ? styles.modalWhiteFixed : ""}`}>
                        {props.arrowShape ? <div className={arrowTypeStyle ? arrowTypeStyle : styles.triangleToprightWhite} /> : null}
                        {props.children}
                    </div>
                    : null
                :
                props.show ?
                    <div className={`${props.className} ${styles.modal}`}>
                        <div style={style} className={`${props.sectionName} ${modalTypeStyle ? modalTypeStyle : styles.modalWhite} ${modalTypeSize ? modalTypeSize : styles.modalSmall} ${!props.showAt ? styles.modalWhiteFixed : ""}`}>
                            {props.arrowShape ? <div className={arrowTypeStyle ? arrowTypeStyle : styles.triangleToprightWhite} /> : null}
                            {props.children}
                        </div>
                    </div> :
                    null}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In functional components if the browser move due to hiding/showing scroll.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      document.body.style.paddingRight = '15px';
    }
    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
      document.body.style.paddingRight = '0px';
    };
  }, [show]);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still my browser is jumping.
https://www.loom.com/share/a76cd9d660af4a7e967277f1d6479a1f?fbclid=IwAR03yLOf5tY5wpFRERUZVSD8VXP2c9ndf1FZ-n2eGjBqI0tpLHYlJxAu0oQ

Comment: Maybe your modal is not unmouting when you close. Maybe you could try without the return statement. So if show is true the browser is hiding the scroll and if its not true it does the opposite. The return statement fires when a component is unmouting.

Answer (score 7):

I have 2 functions to handle this, when open modal and when close modal

```
openModal(){
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: true
        })
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }

closeModal(){
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: false
        })
        document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Short and elegant

The same solution as previous proposed, but the most elegant:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = isOpen ? "hidden" : "unset";
  }, [isOpen]);
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it works when I check the show of the show.
Example in functional component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    else document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
  }, [show]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried according to Mehran Motiee's but every time I close a cookie consent, it clears the body style. So I tried adding class list instead and it works.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (show) document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden');
    else document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden');
  }, [show]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal), one can use these callbacks provided:

```
onAfterOpen
onRequestClose
```

the component will look like this:

```
function App() {
      
  const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
    
  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  function afterOpenModal() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }

  function closeModal() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
      >
        <button onClick={closeModal}>close</button>
        <div>I am a modal</div>
        <form>
          <input />
          <button>tab navigation</button>
          <button>stays</button>
          <button>inside</button>
          <button>the modal</button>
        </form>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also use add the following class to your div containing the Modal:

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
}
```

[Considerations for styling a modal](https://css-tricks.com/considerations-styling-modal/#fixed)

> The point of this is that a user could be scrolled down the page, trigger a modal, and have the modal be just as centered-and-visible as it would be if they weren’t scrolled.

Comment: This does not work for Ant Design 4, not tested on 5