# Remove backgroundImage on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I currently have a `<Login/>` page, and a `<Dashboard/>`.

The login page has a background of `#222`, and when you login the Dashboard has a background of `whitesmoke`

The way I am doing this is having this on the body css:

```
body {
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

and this in the `Dashboard.js`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "whitesmoke";
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
}
```

Up to now, this was working. But I now have an Image as my background on the Login page, as seen here:

```
body {
    background-color: #222222;
    background: url('../../public/img/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

but my Dashboard inherits the background image, even when I put something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = null;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "whitesmoke";
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
}
```

How do I get around this? 
Thanks

Comment: `null` is not a valid value of backgroundImage and it gets ignored by the browser. Use `document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'none';`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use classes instead?

---

```
componentWillMount() {
  $('body').addClass('has-background');
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  $('body').removeClass('has-background');
}
```

Also, you may want to abstract those `addClass / removeClass` and use [emits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694570/when-where-and-how-to-add-class-to-the-document-body-when-using-react-js).